# Ruby: iterating over a hash and formatting the display

Tags: ruby, hash, format, iteration

Say I have a hash like so:

```
top_billed = { ghostbusters: 'Bill Murray', star_wars: 'Harrison Ford' }
```

What would be the best way to format it in a nice, human-readable way?
For example if you called a method on the hash and it displayed the hash as a capitalized list, minus underscores.

- "Ghostbusters: Bill Murray
- Star Wars: Harrison Ford

I guess iterating over the array and using gsub to remove underscores then capitalizing might work, but I was wondering whether there was anything more elegant.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "minus underscores"?

Comment: If you remove underscores from `:star_wars`, you get `:starwars`.

Comment: What is the logic for having a double quote at the beginning of `Ghostbusters`?

Comment: minus underscores aka without underscores. and I wanted them replaced with a space. Please ignore double quote; it was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive solution:

```
top_billed = { ghostbusters: { my_name: 'Bill Murray', my_age: 29 }, star_wars: { my_name: 'Harrison Ford' }, something_esle: 'Its Name'}

def print_well(key, value, indent)
  key = key.to_s.split('_').map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
  if Hash === value
    puts "#{key}: "
    value.each do |k, v|
      print_well k, v, indent + 1
    end
  else
    puts "#{' '*indent}#{key}: #{value}"
  end
end

def print_hash hash, indent=0
  hash.each do |key, value|
    print_well key, value, indent
  end
end

print_hash top_billed
```

Comment: I get using gems but as someone learning the basics of the language it would be helpful to know how things actually work.

Answer (score 0):

Manually:

```
top_billed.each do |k, v|
  puts k.to_s.gsub("_", " ") + ": " + v
end
```

if you are using Rails or ActiveSupport, you can also use the "[humanize](http://apidock.com/rails/String/humanize)" method (on a String).

Comment: perhaps a separate issue but how come when this is executed inside irb, it displays as expected but irb displays the final output as the original hash?

Comment: irb shows both the output (so the result of "puts") and the result of each instruction typed - this is handy for debugging, which irb is all about.